# (Possibly) weird object in Excel VBA I need to retrieve values from

Tags: vba, excel

I am using some shared dll (I don't have access to the source code) in Excel/VBA in which I am creating various objects from. Amongst those an object named **crv** of type **ITermStructure** (see the below image).

This object contains various properties such as

1. Country
2. CurveID
3. etc.

However, from the below picture of the watches window there is a lot of properties called

1. 'Item 1'
2. 'Item 2'
3. etc.

of type **Variant/Object/IPoint**.

My guess is that each item is just a simple **IPoint** object holding (X,Y)-coordinates.

The tricky part, thus, is how I retrieve the values from

1. 'Item 1'
2. 'Item 2'
3. etc.

I am a bit tricked by the names **'Item 1', 'Item 2'** (with a space!) which tells me that is some sort of VBA element away from my knowledge.

Calling **crv.** and then choosing among the different possibilites does not yield any information other than I can retrieve/set the values of **crv.Country, crv.CurveID** etc., but no information on **'Item 1', 'Item 2'** etc.

Has Anybody got an idea of:

1. What type of construction this is?
2. How I retrieve the values from **'Item 1', 'Item 2'** etc.?

Any help kindly appreciated!

Christian

[image: (Possibly) weird object in Excel VBA I need to retrieve values from]

Comment: Wall of text! Sorry but you might want to consider formatting your text a little bit so that it is much easier to read and pleasant to the eye. I suspect many people will not read your question in that format.

Comment: So looks are more important than content? :-) I tried reformatting, though!

Comment: +1 For the much pleasant format. Well looks are quite important. It has to be pleasing for someone to want to read it! :)

Comment: Is it [this IPoint](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/subscriptions/microsoft.office.interop.excel.ipoint_members)? If yes, there is a bunch of public properties that can be accessed, but apparently they are not supposed to. Can you click on the + buttons to see what is under each  item?

Answer (score 0):

Your `crv` object seems like a collection, so you have indexed access to the stored *items*, e.g. `crv(1)`.

If this does not work, then the object didn't define a default member of its class, in which case one should explicitly index into the property: `crv.Item(1)`

Comment: I thought so initially, but calling something likec crv(1) yields an error as well as for instance crv(1).X.